# New to Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Task at hand Create a Stored Procedure called MentoringCount() which displays the professor name and number of students being mentored the output needs to be sorted by professor name and then I need to create a second procedure that doesn't need to count and needs to show the professors who are not mentoring which I assume I can import most of the first procedure and edit the mentor =1 to mentor = 0

I'm currently stuck on creating the first procedure here is my written code below I'm getting an error on the line that contains "Order by professor.professorName" I think I'm the right track but not entirely sure if I am or if my code is a complete mess

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MentoringCount()
 BEGIN
 SELECT 
     professor.ProfessorName,    
     (COUNT(student_professor.student_professor_id)) AS 'StudentNo'
 FROM professor
 LEFT JOIN student_professor
 ON student_professor.ProfessorId = professor.ProfessorId 
    AND student_professor.Mentor =1;
 ORDER BY professor.professorName
 END //
 DELIMITER;
```

Below are the tables with relevent info for the task

```
StudentProfessor Table
student_professor_id
ProfessorID
StudentNo
Mentor

professor Table
ProfessorID
ProfessorName

student Table
studentno
```

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY professor.ProfessorId`

Comment: simple syntax error: you have a semicolon right in front of `ORDER BY`

Comment: I've removed the semicolon above then the error moves to line 10 "END" where it's expecting a semicolon I've tried adding it there as well.

Comment: and a final tip for writing such statements:   For testing, just copy paste and run anything between `BEGIN .. END` without the `CREATE PROCEDURE` part. When the query runs and gives you the correct output, then it's time to create a procedure.  Saves alot of headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple syntax error in your code, the semicolon is in the middle of the statement.

Also, your query might only return a single row, because you use the `COUNT()` aggregate function on an undefined aggregate. When using such functions, you should always include a `GROUP BY` statement. Mysql has the weird default behaviour to just assume you want to group ALL rows instead of throwing an error message.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MentoringCount()
 BEGIN

 SELECT 
     professor.ProfessorName,    
     COUNT(student_professor.student_professor_id) AS 'StudentNo'
 FROM professor
 LEFT JOIN student_professor
 ON student_professor.ProfessorId = professor.ProfessorId 
    AND student_professor.Mentor = 1
 GROUP BY professor.professorName;

 END //
 DELIMITER;
```

A note on the `DELIMITER`:
As you need to store complete statements (with ending `;`) inside the procedure, the `DELIMITER` changes the character sequence during the procedure creation to `//`, so the `;` *inside* the procedure is processed as text and not part of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

This is the reason why the syntax error only appears when *executing* the procedure and not while *creating* it. During creation, the inside of the `CREATE` statement is just some (almost) plain text stored as the procedure. It is not being parsed.

**EDIT**

You select *ALL* professors and then `LEFT JOIN` the mentoring relationship.  If you only want to see rows that match `Mentor = 1`, you can either move your `ON` condition to a `WHERE` clause, or switch your `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

i.e.

```
 SELECT .. FROM professor
 LEFT JOIN student_professor
      ON student_professor.ProfessorId = professor.ProfessorId 
 WHERE student_professor.Mentor = 1
 GROUP BY professor.professorName;
```

or

```
 SELECT .. FROM professor
 INNER JOIN student_professor
      ON student_professor.ProfessorId = professor.ProfessorId 
         AND student_professor.Mentor = 1
 GROUP BY professor.professorName;
```

If you want to understand why, please look up the difference between `INNER` and `LEFT` JOINs, and the difference between `ON` and `WHERE` clause in the documentation.

Comment: Ah now I get it and the procedure imports and displays the names of the professors and how many students they are mentoring but It's also displaying professors who aren't. How do I adjust that?